# Calcualted column formual "=TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")-[Last Update]" will show 44,055 if the [Last Update] column is empty

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula, modern-experience, calculated-column

I am working on an online SharePoint site, and I created a calculated column with the following formula:-

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")-[Last Update]
```

[image]
now the formula is working well if the [Last Update] contain value, while if the [Last Update] is empty then the formula will return `44,055` so how I can fix this? to force the formula to return null if the `[Last Update]` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Last Update]),"",TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")-[Last Update])
```

Comment: worked well thanks alot